# Xcode 6 Segue with UINavigationItem

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

I've just created a Segue from a ViewController (which is embedded in a UINavigationController) to another ViewController. It seems like that the new Segue types do not create the UINavigationItem (which contains the title label) on Segue creation as the push Segue type did in iOS 7. I've noticed this fact because I couldn't enter any title for the "new" ViewController after I created the Segue. There is also no place where I can properly place a bar button item.

I couldn't find anything regarding this fact in the Segue documentation so I was wondering if the UINavigationItem isn't automatically being created anymore. It doesn't even show up in the document outline. Does somebody know something about that? Maybe it's just a Xcode Beta 3 issue?

Here is a picture of the segue in the attributes inspector:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is a push segue?

Comment: @Rog I've added a picture of the segue to the question.

Comment: I guess it's a bug, it wouldn't make any sense removing it when it's a push segue.

Comment: Have you tried Beta 3?

Comment: I'm sorry it's Beta 3. I'll correct it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug, it normally fixes it self after restarting Xcode but quick fix is just to drag a navigation item from the object library onto the view controller.